# Subtracting a list from a list of lists

Tags: python

I am trying to delete list from a list of lists. For instance:

```
n = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [43,2,5]]
m = [4,5,6]
```

I want to subtract m[0], from all the values in n[0], then go to m[1], and subtract m[1] from all the values in n[1], etc....

Finally, I want to have something like this as my output

```
Output = [[3,2,1], [3,2,1], [37,4,1]]
```

Here is my code:

```
def diff(n,m):
    for i in range(0,3):
        newlist = [[abs(m[i]-value) for value in sublist]
                   for sublist in n]
    return newlist
n = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [43,2,5]]
m = [4,5,6]

diff(n,m)

Output = [[3,2,1], [3,2,1], [37,4,1]]
```

Comment: OK, and what is your question?

Comment: My code is not working as expected, what I'm I getting wrong? Thanks

Comment: This is my current output
''' Output = [[5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 2], [37, 4, 1]] '''

Comment: According to your question, your output is the same as what you want to have as your output. What do you mean it's not working as expected? Give full details in the question; see [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for that, the output I posted there is what I expected not the output my code is giving. The output my code is giving is [[5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 2], [37, 4, 1]], but what I expected is [[3,2,1], [3,2,1], [37,4,1]]. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a pythonic list comprehension (with `zip` instead of indexes)...

```
[[abs(b-x) for x in a] for a, b in zip(n, m)]
```

Comment: what's the advantage of this over indexes?

Comment: @Eniola It's shorter, faster, and pythonic.

Comment: Thanks. And what advice can you give to a beginner in python? It seems hard and sometimes frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to only subtract `m[i]` from the values in `n[i]`, but your code is subtracting `m[i]` from all elements of `n`, but then only returning the result from subtracting `m[2]` since you overwrite `newlist` in each pass through the `for` loop. Here's a list comprehension that does what you want:

```
n = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [43,2,5]]
m = [4,5,6]

o = [[abs(v-m[i]) for v in n[i]] for i in range(len(m))]
print(o)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [37, 4, 1]]
```